# How to test speed of a website through proxy server in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to build application which tests the speed of website(website is inserted by user) through various proxy servers (also inserted by user). How can it be done in `nodejs`?

Comment: The same way it would be with any other language/platform. Measure an average time between a request and a response. The question is too broad. Consider reasking it once you have specific problem with implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, connect to the proxy server and send ping request through that proxy server.
See [net-ping](https://github.com/nospaceships/node-net-ping) and [ping-wrapper](https://github.com/langpavel/node-ping-wrapper)